# R: Find variables supplied to functions with the '...' argument with exists()

Tags: r

I want to supply an optional variable to a function, let the functions check whether this argument was supplied, and let it perform the corresponding set of computations. I thought I can use the '...' operator for that.

The simplest example I can think of (which sadly failed) is this:

```
monkeyfun = function(...){

     if (exists("monkey")){
       return('monkey found')
     } else {
       return('monkey not found')
     }

  }
```

Now `monkeyfun(monkey=0)` as well as `monkeyfun()` both return `"monkey not found"`.

As a sanity check, defining `monkey = 1` outside of the function works and returns `"monkey found"`.

The documentation on the `'...'` argument doesn't really help me understand this issue and I was unable to find a formulation of this question that gives matching results on here (I do understand this question is basic and most likely discussed somewhere)...

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `hasArg`:

```
monkeyfun <- function(...) {
  if (hasArg("monkey")) {
    return('monkey found')
  } else {
    return('monkey not found')
  }
}
monkeyfun()
# [1] "monkey not found"
monkeyfun(monkey=0)
# [1] "monkey found"
```

Comment: I was playing around with `hasArg()` just now... it showed the following unexpected behavior though... take the following function:
`tfun = function(x = 0){ if( hasArg(name = 'x')) { print('found') } }`
If I run it without supplying `x` (which should nevertheless trigger the default) it does not tell me `"found"`.

Comment: @Affaeng: why is that unexpected? If you call `tfun()` with no arguments, then there is not an argument `x` in the call. So `hasArg("x")` quite correctly returns `FALSE`. It's irrelevant that `x` is a formal argument to `tfun`. As mentioned in the *See Also* section to `?hasArg`, you might want to read `?missing`.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `match.call` since it returns  all the function arguments specified by their full names. Here How I would rewrite your function:

```
monkeyfun = function(...){
  params <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  if ("monkey" %in% names(params)){  ## note how I change the test here
    return('monkey found')
  } else {
    return('monkey not found')
  }

}

# monkeyfun()
# [1] "monkey not found"
# > monkeyfun(monkey=0)
# [1] "monkey found"
```

Comment: I think `params <- list(...)` is a little simpler and easier to understand.  I believe it will work the same here.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this dialog with the R interpreter. Generally existence is tested by seeing if the length is greater than 0:

```
 monkeyfun = function(...){
 print(str(list(...)))
   }
 monkeyfun(monkey=0)
#List of 1
# $ monkey: num 0
#NULL
 monkeyfun = function(...){
 loclist = list(...)
  if (exists(loclist$monkey)){
        return('monkey found')
      } else {
        return('monkey not found')
      } }
 monkeyfun(monkey=0)
#Error in exists(loclist$monkey) : invalid first argument
 monkeyfun = function(...){
 loclist = list(...)
  if (length(loclist$monkey)){
        return('monkey found')
      } else {
        return('monkey not found')
      } }
 monkeyfun(monkey=0)
#[1] "monkey found"
 monkeyfun(monk_uncle=1)
#[1] "monkey not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how non-standard evaluation works in R (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-dots). You can print a list of the objects passed to the function using `...` using `print(list(...))`, you can evaluate them using `eval(substitute(alist(...)))`. In your case you want to check to see if an object is defined in `...`. This can be accomplished by the following code.

```
 monkeyfun = function(...){
 print(list(...))
   if ("monkey"%in%names(list(...))){
     return('monkey found')
   } else {
     return('monkey not found')
   }

 }
```

Comment: The mechanism offered by Hadley is not typical R practice. It's more typical to assign the result of `list(...)` to a name and then work with that object, perhaps in combination with `match.arg`. I also do not think this has much to do with non-standard evaluation